# How to use route to view static page and the best place to put a group of static files in Laravel

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.7

I'm building a website in Laravel that shows website templates, I have a preview option so the user can view a demo for the templates.

I don't want to put the demos in view folder or as blades.

What is the best place to put these files?

Folder structure:

```
- demos
  - template1
    - index.html
    - css
      - app.css
  - template2
    - index.html
    - css
      - app.css
```

My Routers:

```
Route::get('/demo/{slug}', 'DemoController@index')->name('demo');
```

and how to route to a static folder?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. I'd put 'em in a new folder in `resources`, personally, but it's really up to you.

Comment: @ceejayoz what about putting them in public folder

Comment: "Doesn't really matter."